# How do I check message author's and mentioned user's highest role positions, and compare them?

Tags: discord.js

I made 2 different variables, and used an if statement

This is what the code looks like

```
    let mentionedRole = message.mentions.roles.first();
    let authorRole = message.member.roles.highest

    if(mentionedRole.position > authorRole.position) {
        message.channel.send(`You don't have access to mute this 
        user. ${message.author}`)
        return
    }
```

The variables at the start don't error, but the if statement did
This is the error I got

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')

I tried it without adding the `.position`, but the command didn't work and no errors happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.mentions.roles.first()` is undefined, because `message.mentions` is an object with all the mentions in the message. You can get the highest role of the first mention like this:

```
message.mentions.members.first().roles.highest
```

Your code should work if the mention is a role. If the mention is a server member, then you need to get it's highest role like that